# How to display a success message

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

How to generate Success Message in Apex without using custom scripts like this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eORm3WtVw9w)

I made a form and a button, this button inserts data into a table with identity PK using PLSQL, I want to display success message with the generated ID

The button has PLSQL like this

```
DECLARE 
  V_ID  INT;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TABLE(COL) VALUES (:VALUE) returning ID into :V_ID ;

  apex_application.g_print_success_message :=
    '<span style="green">'||:V_ID || 'added </span>';
END;
```

the row is inserted into the database but Nothing is displayed

The Video is useless to me because he/she altered an existing message, this is why `apex_application.g_print_success_message` worked for the author of the video but I want to display a message like that in the first place, so how to display the message I just created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- create a hidden page item, let's call it `P1_RETURNED_ID`
- button runs a process, right? That's your PL/SQL block. Change it to

  ```
  insert into your_table (col) values (:P1_SOME_VALUE)
  returning id into :P1_RETURNED_ID;
  ```
- Put this into the "Success message" property:

  ```
  Added was &P1_RETURNED_ID.
  ```

  (literally, ampersand (`&`) followed by item name (`P1_RETURNED_ID`) followed by dot (`.`)

Comment: ah I see, Thanks. No my button didn't run a process, the PL/SQL was in the button. I can do it like you described this is acceptable for me.

Comment: Was exactly looking for the same, only mistake I did was having the item in lower case in the success message property. Thanks a ton @littlefoot.

Comment: You're welcome, @Venkat.